# Questions as subjects

Tags: questions, subjects

How can I use a question as a subject of the sentence?

For example:

> How did the big bang occur has always attracted scientists.

What is wrong with this sentence?

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your example?

Comment: It was the wrong answer on a quiz.

Comment: "The question 'How did X happen?' is..." or "The question of how X happened is..."

Comment: So, the example is grammatically wrong?

Comment: Yes, the answer does not follow the rule for embedding a question as a complement clause. In a real question, you exchange the auxiliary and the subject, but that's a step you don't do when embedding. That way your listener can tell immediately that it's not a real question, but rather the subject clause.

Comment: thanks for clear explanation.

Comment: Just reword it without inversion: "How the big bang occurred has always attracted scientists". The meaning is "The answer to the question 'How did the big bang occur?' has always attracted scientists".

Comment: thank you BillJ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> [*How did the big bang occur*] *has always attracted scientists.*

Embedded subordinate interrogative clauses (embedded questions) don't normally have subject-auxiliary inversion. They can function as subject provided they follow the usual rule. Your sentence should be:

> [*How the big bang occurred*] *has always attracted scientists.*

The meaning can be glossed as "The answer to the question 'How did the big bang occur?' has always attracted scientists".

Incidentally, you might consider replacing the verb "attracted" with either of the verbs "intrigued" or "fascinated".